# Java Error - Missing method body or declare abstract

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

*emphasized text*I've been working on this problem for a while and managed to get rid of almost all the errors on this class. This error keeps saying I'm missing method body or declare abstract but I just don't see it. I've managed to complete another class almost similar to this but this one seems to be acting strangely. Can someone please help me out? Thank you if you do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HockeyPlayer extends StudentAthlete
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    HockeyPlayer athlete1 = new HockeyPlayer("Dave", 111111, 15, 3.2, 2, 3);

    athlete1.writeOutput();
  }

  private int assist = 0;
  private int goal = 0;

  public HockeyPlayer()
  {
    super();
    goal = 0;
    assist = 0;
  }

  public int getAssist()
  {
    return  assist;
  }

  public void setAssist(int newAssist)
  {
    if (0 >= newAssist)
    {
      assist = newAssist;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid Assists");
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid Assists");
      int tempAssist = keyboard.nextInt();
      setAssist(tempAssist);
    }
  }

  public int getGoal()
  {
    return goal;
  }

  public int setGoal(int newGoal)
  {
    if (0 >= newGoal)
    {
      goal = newGoal;
    }

    else
    {
      System.out.println("Invalid Goals");
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid Goals");
      int tempGoal = keyboard.nextInt();
      setGoal(tempGoal);
    }
  } 

  public HockeyPlayer(String initialName, int initialStudentNumber, int initialJersey, double initialGpa, int initialGoal, int initialAssist)
{
    super (initialName, initialStudentNumber,initialJersey, initialGpa);
    setGoal(initialGoal);
    setAssist(initialAssist);
}

  public HockeyPlayer(String initialName, int initialStudentNumber, int initialJersey, double initialGpa)
  {
    super (initialName, initialStudentNumber, initialJersey, initialGpa);
    goal = 0;
    assist= 0;
  }

  public HockeyPlayer(String initialName, int initialStudentNumber)
  {
    super (initialName, initialStudentNumber);
    goal = 0;
    assist = 0;    
  }

  public HockeyPlayer(String initialName)
  {
    super(initialName);
    goal = 0;
    assist = 0;
  }

  public void writeOutput(); // THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
  {
    super.writeOutput();
    System.out.println("Goals: " + goal);
    system.out.println("Assists: " + assist);
  }
}
```

Comment: `public int setGoal(int newGoal)` ... what is this method suppose to return?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
public int setGoal(int newGoal)
```

to

```
public void setGoal(int newGoal)
```

Setter methods usually don't have a return type (and based on the fact that you don't try to return anything, you probably didn't intend it to have an `int` return type).

Also change

```
public void writeOutput();
```

to

```
public void writeOutput()
```

Comment: I actually have a different error and managed to fix the old one. what am i doing wrong here?